# Compile on linux and debug on Windows with gdb?

Tags: linux, windows, fortran, gdb, cross-platform

I have fortran90 code that I usually compile on a cluster to which I connect via putty from Windows.

I am trying to use gdbgui which runs on Windows but I am having troubles loading the fortran compiled exe in gdbgui on Windows. The exe runs fine on the centOS cluster and I have compiled it with ifort using -g flag and it works properly in gdb.

Is this even possible or do I have to compile in Windows to be able to debug in Windows?

Comment: You normally have to compile in Windows. You can run Windows executables in Linux using wine, but not the other way round. You probably also cannot debug a Windows executable using a Linux debugger either, not even with wine.

Comment: @VladimirF yes I found that out wasting a few hours. No compiling on one machine and debugging in another.